# MySQL Lock only one row

Tags: mysql

I am using `SELECT FOR UPDATE` in MySQL to lock the selected rows according to my condition. But I want to lock only one row instead of all the selected rows.

Tried using `LIMIT 1` but still locks all the selected rows.
Here is my Transaction -

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT * FROM userDetail WHERE userStatus=0 order by createdOn desc limit 1 FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED;
commit;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT * FROM userDetail WHERE id= (select id from userDetail wher userStatus=0 order by createdOn desc limit 1 )
FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED;
commit;
```

try this.

update

session 1
[image]
session 2
[image]
my table data
[image]
before session 1 commit
[image]

Comment: Hi @lant tried the same. It will still lock the entire selected rows instead of one.

Comment: what is you mysql version and how  do you check the number of locked rows.@SoumakPoddar

Comment: I use `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` and in `TRANSACTIONS` part contains lock info

Comment: MySQL version is 8.0.22

Comment: To check the number of locked rows run 2 different transactions on the DB. While the first one has still not committed/rolled back start the second one. In the second one, no results are returned as the first transaction locks all selected rows, and the skip lock doesn't find any next free row.

Comment: Thanks @lant. I had one more small doubt. What if both the queries are same? In this case, select query in session 2 is different?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by the same query. If two queries are the same, their results should also be the same. In the first query, if all rows are locked, the second query will not return any results because their results are the same and all are locked by the first query@SoumakPoddar